# ffmpeg - creating manifest file for smooth streaming

Tags: ffmpeg, smooth-streaming

I'm new to ffmpeg (and video encoding), and i'm trying to understand how do i create a manifest file for IIS
i've tried creating the .ismv filem but it did not create the manifest file, i've saw the ismindex tool under the ffmpeg tools folder, but didn't quite understand how to use it.

Comment: `ismindex` must be compiled first. I assume you run `make ismindex` in the `tools` directory (I haven't tried).

Comment: did you install IIS Media Services already? what's your goal?y ou wanna play the movie? or you want to extract the manifest for some other reason?